# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception When I add @PUT method

Tags: java, maven, jersey, put

I am working on a rest api using Jersey. I need to add a `@PUT` method but it throws an exception.

This is the method I am trying to add right now:

```
@Path("/login")
public class LoginController {
...
    @PUT
    @Path("/user")
    @Consumes("application/json;charset=utf-8")
    @Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
    public String putUser(@QueryParam("user")LoginUser lu) {
        return "login failed";
    }
...
}
```

In reality there is more content in the method but the content does not matter. When this method exists in the class, I get the following exception when trying to access the server:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
root cause

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)`enter code here`
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

There are also other `@PUT` methods in the class that work as they should but when I add this new one, everything stops working.

This is the content of my web.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>REST API</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

If I change the `@PUT` annotation to `@GET` and remove the `@Consumes` annotation, everything works. Why can I not add a new `@PUT`?

Comment: What if you just removes the `@Consumes` annotation? Does it work?

Comment: If you are sending the LoginUser in the body (json), you have to remove @QueryParam("user")

Comment: @Nathan No, not unless I also change PUT to GET.

Comment: @Héctor Thank you! Thats such a stupid mistake. I will accept this if you post it as an answer.

Comment: I just realized as well that you can't pass parameters in a put request query ^^

Comment: @Nathan Well, you can! Just not the way I did.

Comment: @OliverNorin Yeah, my comment wasn't clear x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you are sending the `LoginUser` as json request body, so you need to remove `@QueryParam("user")`.